# Do using multiple access points affect WiFi performance?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, ssid

I use an additional WiFi access point on my router. One for personal use and other for guest access. But if I leave the guest mode on, will it pose any issue to my other connection. Will there be any performance issues?

Comment: no, they should use different channels. as long as you are not in a heavily contested area. having 2 or 4 active channels should not present significant problem.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hi @FrankThomas. Both my WiFi profiles are working on the same channel (I checked with the 'vistumbler' app). I cannot find an option to change them separately. Only a common option is given in my router settings. Will it affect my performance now?

Comment: are they providing the same SSID? if so it will probably be fine. they are on the same channel in order to prevent reconnection. the two APs should be able to coordinate their function.

Comment: I think, I confused WiFi profile with SSID. I believe it is SSID. As I said, in the "vistumber' app, both are showing same mac address and channel.